# Parsing a Nested JSON

Tags: java, android, json

**Code**::

```
Object obj=jsonobject.get("results");
```

---

the `obj` contains:

```
[
    {
        "providedLocation": {
            "latLng": {
                "lat": 12.931088,
                "lng": 77.620949
            }
        },
        "locations": [
            {
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 12.931088,
                    "lng": 77.620949
                },
                "adminArea5Type": "City",
                "adminArea4": "Bangalore Urban",
                "adminArea5": "Bangalore",
                "adminArea4Type": "County",
                "street": "Sarjapur Road",
                "adminArea1": "IN",
                "adminArea3": "Karnataka",
                "type": "s",
                "displayLatLng": {
                    "lat": 12.928883,
                    "lng": 77.617502
                },
                "linkId": 0,
                "postalCode": "560095",
                "dragPoint": false,
             .
```

.
.
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

---

**What i am trying to do**:: I an trying to extract   `"Bangalore"` from `"adminArea5"`

---

**What i tried**:: i tried to use code to convert into json

```
jsonobject = new JSONObject(obj);
```

what i am getting back is `{}`

---

**Question**::

- Where i am doing wrong ?
- how to correct myself in code?
- How to do parsing to this scenario

**Code i used**::

```
JSONObject jsonobject,jsonobject1;  

            try {
                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT.trim());
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(Content);   
                //jsonobject1 = (JSONObject)jsonobject.get("results");
                Object obj=jsonobject.get("results");

                jsonobject = new JSONObject(obj);
```

Comment: post the code you are using for parsing that object

Comment: @blackbelt ....Please look at the update ... i have added the code

Comment: the root is a `JSONObject`. It does contains a `JSONArray` with key results, that contains a JSONArray of locations. Each location is a JSONObject that contains the key you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you have `JSONObject` only, while trying to get `results` that only returns `JSONArray`. Here zero based index have used, if you have multiple location array, try to put in loop.

```
JSONObject jsonobject,jsonobject1;  
    try {
        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT.trim());
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        jsonobject = new JSONObject(Content);   
        //jsonobject1 = (JSONObject)jsonobject.get("results");
        JSONArray locationArray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("locations");
        String adminArea5 = locationArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("adminArea5");
        jsonobject = new JSONObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a JSONArray, so create a new JSONArray(obj) instead, then you can make a JSONObject out of the first item in the resulting JSONArray.

```
JSONObject item = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(obj);
JSONObject list_item = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray locations_jsonarray = list_item.getJSONArray("locations");
JSONObject locations_list_item = locations_jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
String value = locations_list_item.getString("adminArea5")
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing your approach is wrong because you are trying to convert `jsonarray to jsonobject`. So

```
{} denote json object

[] denote json array
```

now code is below:

```
JSONObject main = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

JSONArray location = main.getJSONArray("locations");

JSONObject location_main = location.getJSONObject(0);

String adminArea5 = location_main.getString("adminArea5");
```